# Next.js 13 _next/image not showing in vercel stage server prod build

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13, next-images

I have the following nextjs middleware.ts config file,

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     * - fonts (font files)
     */
    '/((?!_next/image|_next/static|api|favicon.ico|fonts).*)',
   ],
};
```

**Optimize next image url:-**

https://{vercel_stage_server_domain}/_next/image?url=

**Optimize next image url in local:-**

http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=

Works fine in local, but nor work in stage server, In stage server it redirect.

How can I prevent the redirection?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because of `/image` or `/static`, try below instead:

```
matcher: [
        // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized. This example skips
        // certain folders and all pathnames with a dot (e.g. favicon.ico)
        '/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)',
    ],
```

References:
https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/routing/middleware

I didn't try to escape that '/'. You may try to escape that by using '\':

```
matcher: ['/((?!api|_next\/static|_next\/image|.png).*)'],
```